# Error while add mail core in project

Tags: cocoa, mailcore

I want to implement mail functionality in my mac application...I have download the code of MailCore framework form [lempsink/mailcore](https://bitbucket.org/lempsink/mailcore/src). But when I add it in my project by simple drag the mailcore.xcodeproject in my project and add the statement "#import " then it is giving the following error:-

MailCore/MailCore.h: No such file or directory in ~Desktop/lempsink-mailcore-007cf0f043c7 2/Examples/MessageSender/MyController.h.

Can anybody help me where am I doing wrong ? and how can I resolve it.

Thanks in Advance